# Grails - GORM - one to many with lookup data

Tags: grails, grails-orm, lookup

I want to use a lookup table to get a list of type codes and the code is saved in product table. Product can have only one category type and it is nullable. Here is my code so far. Is it the right way to go? I thought the id mapping from CategoryType will be used as the column in Product. but it is trying to find the category_cd_id in the product table. Even if I map the CategoryCd to category_cd in static mapping it is not used.

```
class Product {
  String productId
  String productName

  CategoryType categoryCd

      static mapping = {
        table 'A_PRODUCT'
        id column:'product_id'
        version false
    } 
}

class CategotyType {
  String categoryCd
  String categoryName

      static mapping = {
        table 'A_CATEGORY_TYPE'
        id column:'category_cd'
        version false
    } 
}
```

Comment: Change your `id` method in `static mapping` to `id name: 'productId'` and `id name: 'categoryCd'`. See (this doc)[http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html] for more info.

Comment: @grantmc thanks. The following is working

    'class Product {
      String productId
      String productName

      CategoryType categoryCd

          static mapping = {
            table 'A_PRODUCT'
            id column:'product_id'
            categoryCd column:'category_cd', type: 'string'
            version false
        } 
    }

    class CategotyType {
      String categoryCd
      String categoryName

          static mapping = {
            table 'A_CATEGORY_TYPE'
            id column: 'category_cd', generator: 'assigned'
            version false
        } 
    }'